# Как указать относительный путь для приложения разворачиваемого на сервере Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, path, war

Вот то, что не получается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если не указывать абсолютный путь, выпадает с ошибкой FieNotFoundException

Я пробовала следющие пути:

`../../../resources/connection.properties`

`src/main/resources/connection.properties`

`web/src/main/resources/connection.properties`

`connection.properties`

`resources/connection.properties`

Вот, что пишет:

`Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ***my attempts*** (The system cannot find the path specified)`

Проект собирается в war

Как же указать относительный путь?

Источник проблем:

```
@Service
public class SocketConnectionPropertiesLoader implements ConnectionPropertiesLoader {
    @Override
    public Properties loadProperties(String pathToProperties) {
        File file = new File(pathToProperties);
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        try {
            properties.load(new FileReader(file));
            return properties;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new SocketConnectionException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Так же я попыталась перенести папку с ресурсами в WEB-INF, к сожалению, так же неудачно

Comment: Кажется, вы не там ищите ошибку. Кажется, она находится в ConnectionPropertiesLoader классе. Покажите его. Только текстом, не надо скриншотов - например тогда не придётся с картинки перепечатывать имена ваших классов - их можно будет просто скопировать из вопроса.

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ добавила

Comment: Попробуйте вот такой код: `try {
    Properties configProperties = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/connection.properties");
    configProperties.load(inputStream);
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Could not load the file");
    e.printStackTrace();
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если файл находится в ресурсах вашего проекта, то можно так:

```
@Value("classpath:/connection.properties")
Resource connectionPropertiesResource;
```

Если файл в корне `resources`, то cпринг его автоматически внедрит. Дальше уже пользуйтесь методами Resource типа [getFile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html#getFile--), чтобы достать содержимое.

Ключевые момент тут (и то что не работает в ваших попытках):

1. файл из корня папки resources при сборке попадает в корень classpath
2. соответственно и загрузку нужно делать из корня classpath (можно и вручную используя `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/connection.properties")` - это то, что спринг делает, если использовать `Resource` с автовнедрением).

Но конкретно для properties более удобно воспользоваться `PropertySource`:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/connection.properties")
public class ConnectionProperties {
}
```

и далее используйте `@Value` или `@Inject` в других бинах:

```
@Service
class SomeOtherService {
    @Value("${value.from.connection.properties}")
    private String someProperty;
}
```

`ConnectionProperties` из примера, должен находится либо в пакете, который попадает под автоматическое сканирование конфигурации, либо явно включен через `@Import`.

Comment: Интересно) но в моем проекте исключительно контекст , ничего больше другого не используется. Возможно, в контекст попимо core входит и SpEL, и все остальное, нужное для таких трюков, в любом случае - полезно в будущем, с использованием более одного артефакта спринг, попробую так, если не выйдет из-за отсутствия нужных зависимостей, посмотрю как это делают в спринг, ну и на крайняк, его же и заюзаю. Спасибо!